# Using vector instead of array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it OK to use `Vector2` or `Vector3` in Unity instead of `float[2]` or `float[3]`?

I often need a data structure for a small group of numbers, but don't want to bother with initializing them. So, could it be considered a bad practice to declare them as vectors?

Comment: If these data structures are vectors use them, otherwise don't abuse them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the data you want to store a Vector? No? Then don't do it.
It's like trying to eat soup with a fork, you can do it but is inefficient.

Comment: OK, but it's tempting especially in case when passing an array as a function parameter. Using Vector parameter makes it clear how many values should be stored in the array.